# Get first and last 6 months in year with timestamp in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to create first and last 6 months in a year, not considering from current date:

```
select DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, GETDATE())-6, 0)
```

I used this, but this gives the first date of 6 months before

Comment: What do you want your output to be? Just the months? Month & year, each date of the year...

Comment: Please show your expected result

Comment: Your statement is not clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DATEFROMPARTS` function can be used for that:

```
SELECT
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),1,1) AS beginningOfYear, 
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(GETDATE()),6,1) AS midOfYear
```